# Loop through list variable in Ansable

Tags: ansible, redhat

I am making an ansible script where a variable file will hold a list of servers, where I will loop through and power them down. It appears that Ansible is changing my list to a string, but maybe I am wrong.

I've tried using "loop", "with_items", and having them on the same line. serverA and ServerB does indeed exist

File dir:

```
taskName/vars/ServerListA.yaml

taskName/tasks/main.yaml

taskName/tasks/shutdown.yaml
```

ServerListA.yaml:

```
---
  evenServers:
    - serverB
    - serverA
```

main.yaml:

```
---
- import_tasks: shutdown.yaml
```

shutdown.yaml:

```
---
  - name: get vars
    include_vars:
      file: ServerListA.yaml
      name: evenServers

  - name: shutdown guest
    vmware_guest_powerstate:
      hostname: virtualCenterName
      state: powered-on
      username: user
      name: "{{ item }}"
      password: pass
      validate_certs: no
    loop:
      - "{{ evenServers }}"
```

**output:**

> TASK [vCenter_Infra_HA_Test : shutdown guest]
>   *********************************************************************************************************  [WARNING]: The value {'evenServers': ['serverA', 'serverB']} (type
>   dict) in a string field was converted to u"{'evenServers': ['serverA',
>   'serverB']}" (type string). If this does not look like what you
>   expect, quote the entire value to ensure it does not change.
>
> failed: [localServer] (item={u'evenServers': [u'serverA',
>   u'serverB']}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false,
>   "item": {"evenServers": ["serverA", "serverB"]}, "msg": "Unable to set
>   power state for non-existing virtual machine : '{'evenServers':
>   ['serverA', 'serverB']}'"}

Answer (score 0):

You are including vars inside a top level 'namespace' with the same name as the first var defined in your included file. Thus, after inclusion, you data looks like this:

```
evenServers:
  evenServers:
    - serverA
    - serverB
```

Since ansible cannot loop over the first level hash (without any other instructions) it transforms it to a string representation to have something to use.

You should transfrom your tasks file like this:

```
---
  - name: get vars
    include_vars:
      file: ServerListA.yaml

  - name: shutdown guest
    vmware_guest_powerstate:
      hostname: virtualCenterName
      state: powered-on
      username: user
      name: "{{ item }}"
      password: pass
      validate_certs: no
    loop: "{{ evenServers }}"
```

I also suggest you fix the indentation in your var file

```
---
evenServers:
  - serverB
  - serverA
```